# justifyContent is not working and I can't change background color of the screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

[image]

I am using native base and in this picture you will see stackedLabel form. I'm trying to move it to the center of the screen but it doesn't work with justifyContent and still stays at the top of the screen. Also I am trying to change background color of the whole screen which is also doesn't work.
Here is the code:

```
 <Container>

       <Content contentContainerStyle={{
        justifyContent:"center",
        flex:1,
        backgoroundColor: #00A577}}>

              <Form style={styles.form}>
        <Field name="email"
        component={this.renderInput}
               validate={[email, required]} />
        <Field
          name="password"
          component={this.renderInput}
          validate={[alphaNumeric, minLength8, maxLength15, required]}

        />
      </Form>
      <Button
full
        style={styles.button}
      onPress={() => this.signin()}
      >
        <Text style={{color:"#ffffff"}}>Sign In</Text>
</Button>



</Content>

          </Container>
```

How can I fix these 2 issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `flex:1` by `flexGrow:1` in contentContainerStyle

Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Form, Item, Input, Button, Text } from 'native-base';
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: "center", flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: "#00A577" }}>
          <Form>
            <Input placeholder="e-mail" />
            <Input placeholder="password" />
          </Form>
          <Button full>
            <Text style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>Sign In</Text>
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container >
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Will it solve both issues with the background color and moving the form to the center?

Comment: this code was working for me. I was getting the form at center and also the background color.

Answer (score -1):

You've a typo on 'backgoroundColor'.

Comment: You should edit the post instead of adding an answer.

Comment: sure. thank you, new to stack overflow @HugoTeixeira